# ImageMagick on Windows VPS

Tags: windows, vps, image

Greetings,

I want a VPS specially to install ImageMagick. My current hosting provider only offers Virtuozzo powered VPSs and they say there is a conflict between the virtualization software and ImageMagick.

But IM does not install any system DLLs so why should it be a conflict? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Get a new hosting provider.  This one is clearly broken.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you REALLY need ImageMagick? For sites like wikimedia, phpBB it is **not** required (another Windows DLL can be used instead... forgot its name.)